# Why does text turn grey when editing a document in R Markdown?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

On occasion, starting paragraphs with excess spaces in R Markdown/RStudio changes the text color from the color I expect to grey. This behavior isn't consistent, and it doesn't affect the output in any appreciable way. Does anyone know what's happening?

On my machine the second **Response** is grey, and all others are blue.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Unnamed"
date: "6/1/2018"
output: pdf_document
---

**Response**

      **Response**

**Response**
      **Response**
```

[image]

[image]

As far as I can tell, everything about the conditions in the two examples is the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is happening in RStudio, right? Then please [edit] the question to include the rstudio tag an mentione it in the question itself. In addition, please try to build a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hopefully these changes are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you process your document you will see something like this:

[image]

The empty line plus before the second "Response" together with the indentation makes markdown interpret this as code. In RStudio code sections are shown with a grey font. In the PDF output, a fixed width font is used and the `**` are treated literally instead of interpreted as commands for bold.

Since there is no empty line between the third and the forth "Response", these are treated as one paragraph, making the indentation irrelevant.

Solution: Do not indent text but only code.